# Increment package number using powershell

Tags: powershell, increment

I have a script to push a package to Octopus which works. I want to push the package a number of times say 10. But to do this I need to increment the package number by 1 each time. I cant upload the same package number twice. The pushing to Octopus works but im not sure where to start with the increment of the package from MyTestPackage.1.1.0.zip to MyTestPackage.1.1.1.zip. The 0 at before the .zip will need to increment by 1 each time.
I was think of a for loop to upload package 10 times?? Any help would be great

```
function PushPackage {
param(
    $OctopusUri,
    $ApiKey,
    $Package
)

try{ 
    Write-Host "Pushing $Package to Octopus"
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath $OctopusExePath
    & $OctopusExePath push --package $Package  --server $OctopusUri --apiKey $ApiKey --logLevel 'verbose'
    Write-Host "Pushing $Package to Octopus - Success"
    } 
catch{
        Write-Host "PUSH PACKAGE Exception--------- $_"
    }
}
$OctopusUri = "https://MyOctopusTest.local"
$ApiKey = "API-CRW9JBMJGUTEUEYEYUE"
$Package = "C:\temp\OctoTest1\MyTestPackage.1.1.0.zip"

PushPackage $OctopusUri $ApiKey $Package
```

Comment: without getting a list of zips already uploaded to octupus, you wouldnt be able to figure out what the version number should be.

Comment: There will be no package in Octopus with that name. So 1 want to upload 10 packages so I will have 1.zip ........ up to 10.zip.